# dsc local configuration manager email me whenever change occurs

Tags: powershell, dsc

I'm running `DSC` with `ConfigurationMode` set to `"ApplyAndAutoCorrect"`
It works fine as it is fixing any issues withing 15 minutes which is default.

I would like to get notified by any means whenever correction occurs.

Only other options for `ConfigurationMode` are `"ApplyOnly"` and `"ApplyAndMonitor"` with the last one reporting changes in logs.

Is there a way I could get notified of corrections happening. If not, is `"ApplyAndAutoCorrect"` option storing info on corrections performed in some file that I could watch for changes?.

Comment: You could parse the event log for configuration changes and alert from there. More info on the events can be found [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2014/01/03/using-event-logs-to-diagnose-errors-in-desired-state-configuration/).